# C# StreamReader Encoding.UTF8 not working

Tags: c#, unicode, streamreader

I have a C# Project in Visual studio which download and parse XML file that contains Korean, Chinese and another unicode characters. For example for korean artist named *Taeyang* it produce XML like this :

```
<name>태양</name>
```

but it returns

```
<name>??</name>
```

I have tried `StreamReader Encoding.Default` but result is

```
<name>íƒœì–‘</name>
```

The code:

```
string address = String.Format("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/{0}?inc=url-rels", mbids[ord]);
HttpWebRequest newRequest = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
               newRequest.Headers["If-None-Match"] = etagProf;
               newRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
var response = newRequest.GetResponse();
// Reader
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF-8);
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

and the xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#">
    <artist type="Person" id="d84e5667-3cbe-4556-b551-9d7e4be95d71">   
        <name>태양</name>
        <sort-name>Taeyang</sort-name><gender>Male</gender>
        <country>KR</country>
        ...........
    </artist>
</metadata>
```

I'm confused, why it happens ? Any idea dude ?

Comment: Are you sure the source file is actually in UTF8?

Comment: Sure, i checked its charset from response header

Comment: Can you share one of your original input xml files?

Comment: @netblognet : just updated my question, please check it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using the code below (notice I comment out 2 of your lines)

```
//newRequest.Headers["If-None-Match"] = "d84e5667-3cbe-4556-b551-9d7e4be95d71";
//newRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
```

and changed your line: `StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF-8);`

to : `StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);`

I got a good result characters wise:
[image]

```
string address = String.Format("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/{0}?inc=url-rels","d84e5667-3cbe-4556-b551-9d7e4be95d71");
HttpWebRequest newRequest = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
//newRequest.Headers["If-None-Match"] = "d84e5667-3cbe-4556-b551-9d7e4be95d71";
//newRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
var response = newRequest.GetResponse();
// Reader
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(data);
```

Comment: I just did it and output íƒœì–‘ again

Comment: @Sag1v: `GetEncoding` is not relied on to determine the *real* text encoding

Comment: @Sag1v - came to the same result. The code runs fine on my machine, too. So if this doesn't solve the problem of Michael Antonio, maybe his OS has some problems handling the UTF-8 code.

Comment: @netblognet could be, but I think the problem resist in the 2 lines I commented out newRequest.Headers["If-None-Match"] = "d84e5667-3cbe-4556-b551-9d7e4be95d71";
newRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";

Comment: hi all, i fixed this problem. please look at my answer. thanks for your time ... nice to share :)

Answer (score 0):

try UTF8 Encoding

`StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(file_name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: @MichaelAntonio is `Encoding.UTF-8` a typo?

Comment: What's the computer's system language and OS you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `Console.WriteLine()` can't output unicode clearly. Everything unicode (e.g. Korean, Chinese) and all characters except a-z and 0-9 can't output as expected cause `Console.WriteLine()` use single font `Raster Font`

But the main problem was about my DB CONNECTION, i forget to add `charset=utf-8` in my connection string